# Can't do anything after receiving Paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal

I am using Paypal's two IPN scripts from github here: https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php however they aren't working.

I send the test IPN using Paypal's tool here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/ and it says it was succesful: "IPN was sent and the handshake was verified."

However, I can't do what I want after that. I've tried inserting into a database or even just sending a success email. Both of these work fine when done on their own but when I add it to the IPN script nothing happens.

PaypalIPN.php (copied from the github)

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
/** @var bool Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used. */
private $use_sandbox = false;
/** @var bool Indicates if the local certificates are used. */
private $use_local_certs = true;
/** Production Postback URL */
const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
/** Sandbox Postback URL */
const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi- bin/webscr';
/** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
/** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
const INVALID = 'INVALID';
/**
 * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
 * should not be enabled in production).
 * @return void
 */
public function useSandbox()
{
    $this->use_sandbox = true;
}
/**
 * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
 * environments).
 * @return void
 */
public function usePHPCerts()
{
    $this->use_local_certs = false;
}
/**
 * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPaypalUri()
{
    if ($this->use_sandbox) {
        return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
    } else {
        return self::VERIFY_URI;
    }
}
/**
 * Verification Function
 * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
 *
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function verifyIPN()
{
    if ( ! count($_POST)) {
        throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
    }
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
        if (count($keyval) == 2) {
            // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
            if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                    $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                }
            }
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
        }
    }
    // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
    if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
        if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) 
    {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
    $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
    if ($this->use_local_certs) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
        'Connection: Close',
    ));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if ( ! ($res)) {
        $errno = curl_errno($ch);
        $errstr = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
    }
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $http_code = $info['http_code'];
    if ($http_code != 200) {
        throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
    if ($res == self::VALID) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }
}
```

This is my IPN handler URL, example_usage.php (also copied from the github, I just added the one line to send an email, which does nothing when I send the test IPN):

```
<?php namespace Listener;
require('PaypalIPN.php');
use PaypalIPN;
$ipn = new PaypalIPN();
// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();
$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();
if ($verified) {
    /*
     * Process IPN
     * A list of variables is available here:
     * 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration- 
guide/IPNandPDTVariables/
     */


//THIS IS THE ONLY PART I HAVE ADDED, BUT NOTHING IS HAPPENING
$name = '' //Get name from form input
$email = '' //Get email from form input
$amount = '' //Get amount from hidden form input
$subject = 'New order from' . $name
$message = 'New order. Amount: ' . $amount

//For some reason this isn't being sent, even if I change $subject and $message to my own string.
$sendemail= mail("***@***.com", $subject, $message);

}
// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was 
received correctly.
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

?>
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is? Thanks if so

Comment: just make sure mail function working on your server. on localhost it needs sendmail package to work.

Comment: Add a logging message to see whether `$verified` is true or false. I suppose, that it is false

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the IPNs are triggering as expected, and are being sent to the URL you expect.

Follow the steps outlined [here](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you'll be able to find the problem, which includes:

1. Local Testing
2. IPN Simulator
3. Sandbox Transaction Testing
4. Deployment
5. Additional tips for troubleshooting.